# Routing query strings in Kohana3

Tags: url-routing, kohana-3

I am trying to route the url http://host/order?servertype=1&plan=1 with the following entry in bootstrap.php

```
Route::set('order', 'order(/<action>)?servertype=<id1>&plan=<id2>', array('id1'=>'[0-9]+','id2'=>'[0-9]+'))
  ->defaults(array(
      'controller' => 'order',
      'action' => 'index',
  ));
```

I am getting error:Unable to find a route to match the URI. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should mark some of the answers that people have given as "accepted". Click the tick image to the left of an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana's routing system is not designed to work with the query string (and the same is true for most frameworks, I believe). If you really need to manipulate the query string in this way, then you'll have to move the logic out of Kohana and into an .htaccess file, using mod_rewrite.

However, the preferred way to perform routing is to use a hierarchical (path-style) URL structure and then use the query string for any information that cannot be represented hierarhically (which can then be accessed directly from the controller via `$_GET`).

This would mean using a URL structure like `http://host/order/<id1>/<id2>` and a routing scheme like:

```
Route::set('order', 'order(/<action>)/<id1>/<id2>', array('id1'=>'[0-9]+','id2'=>'[0-9]+'))
  ->defaults(array(
      'controller' => 'order',
      'action' => 'index',
  ));
```

However, when using this type of URL structure, it's better to use more descriptive tokens in the URL than plain numeric IDs. So you might consider using ["slugs"](http://www.andrewingram.net/articles/readable_url_slugs/) to identify your server types and plan types, which would give your more readable and SEO-friendlu URLs like `http://host/order/server-type/plan`.